# Best way to check if form was submitted (php)

Tags: php, forms

I'm learning PHP and specifically how to secure php forms.

I'm reading an article entitled "[Sanitize and Validate Data with PHP Filters](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters--net-2595)" wherein the author checks if the form was submitted using the following code:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
  // do something...
}
```

Which does work, but I've read that its best to use input filters (i.e. filter_input).

Secondly, using filter_input would also stop netbeans from nagging me about not "accessing the superglobal $_POST Array directly"

So I wrote the following:

```
function is_form_submit() {
    $request = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "REQUEST_METHOD");
    return $request === 'POST' ? true : false;
}
```

Which could be used like so:

```
if ( is_form_submit() ) {
    // do something...
}
```

So my question is: **doesn't my code achieve the same thing?** If not, why not. Please advise.

Comment: `isset($_POST['Submit'])` only works if you have an input element with the name `"Submit"` whereas `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'` is a more generic solution. To check specifically for a form submission, you could check whether the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`

Comment: also... `return $request === 'POST' ? true : false;` === `return $request === 'POST';`

Comment: you can also check simply `if (!empty($_POST))`,normally i used to check the submitted value

Comment: I usually do a `isset` with the default parameters that are always sent plus I have tokens sent with each post and validating them tells me that the post was submitted and came from my form.

Comment: well, `filter_input()` requires PHP 5.2+ and it is probably slower than `isset()` (not tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your code would achieve the same result in most cases, it is not the same as the `isset` call.

What your code does is checks if the `REQUEST_METHOD` is `POST`. That is, it checks if the user made a POST request to access the current page.

What the `isset` does is checks if something with the name of `Submit` was sent via `POST`. This usually happens when your submit button is `<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />`, as clicking that (or hitting enter in a text field and it's the first submit button) will result in `$_POST['Submit']` being set.

To see the different behaviours, compare the results of `curl -X POST your-url.com/page.php` with `curl -F Submit=submit your-url.com/page.php`.

Comment: I ran both commands on the page with the form. They both loaded the page. What should I be seeing?

Comment: I marked this as the answer as this was the clearest answer for me. however, I still dont get what I was "supposed" to see by running the curl commands you posted.

Comment: If you use the `isset` check only, then the first command won't work, whereas the second will. If you use the `filter_input` check, then both will work.

Answer (score 1):

filter_input is untouched user input.

Some scripts add/modify $_POST and $_GET directly. Fine if your code is fail-safe, but if something goes wrong with the manipulated keys/values, there could be errors.

```
filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'requiredID' )
```

Would not be affected by the type of coding below

```
$_POST['requiredID'] = brokenFunction( $_POST['requiredID'] );
```